# DNS Server list not updating after DNS migration

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

Toady I'm migrating a DNS/DHCP server from Server 2008 on Xen to Server 2012 R2 on VMware.  Things went ok for the most part.  DHCP is working just fine and has been tested.  I manually set one test machine to point to the new DNS server and tested things there.  It works fine.

**The problem** is that when I do an ipconfig /renew and ipconfig /all, the machines don't see the new DNS server in the list.

I have set the new DNS server to the top of the list on the DHCP server, and added it at the server (not just scope) level so that everyone should point there.  The output of ipconfig /all shows that the DHCP server is right, but it shows the old list of DNS servers.  I don't do a lot of work on these services so if someone could shed some light on the issue I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Also:  I have checked the log for DNS and there are no type 31 events indicating failed DNS updates.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there were also DNS servers set on certain scopes at the scope level which is more specific than the server level.  Those took precedence and my server level DNS server list was ignored.  We removed the scope-level DNS lists and the server-level list started applying properly.  Pretty simple, just didn't see it.